# Program throws errors at random (vb.net)

Tags: vb.net

I am using [this sample](http://download.cnet.com/Keylogger-DLL/3000-2094_4-10397887.html) as a basis for a program I'm making. After approximately 618 keystrokes, the program throws this error:

```
CallbackOnCollectedDelegate was detected
Message: A callback was made on a garbage collected delegate of type 'KeyLogger!KeyLogger.CallBackFunction+DelegateCallBack::Invoke'. This may cause application crashes, corruption and data loss. When passing delegates to unmanaged code, they must be kept alive by the managed application until it is guaranteed that they will never be called.
```

The error is thrown most times the application is run, but not every time and not at the same keystroke count. From the error message, I think it sounds like the garbage collector is collecting the delegate, how can I prevent this?

The program I made is essentially a modified version of that vb.net project, but it does not actually store the keystrokes.

Thank you for your help!

Code within CallBack.vb:

```
Option Strict Off
Option Explicit On
Module CallBackFunction
    '******************************************************************************************
    '     Sample for retrieving keystrokes  by use of the "kbLog32.dll"
    '                      (c) 2004 by Nadeem Afanah.
    '******************************************************************************************

    'CallBack function
    Delegate Sub DelegateCallBack(ByVal msg As Integer, ByVal wParam As Integer, ByVal lParam As Integer)

    Sub CallBack(ByVal msg As Integer, ByVal wParam As Integer, ByVal lParam As Integer)
        'here we track only WM_CHAR and WM_KEYDOWN
        If msg = WM_KEYDOWN Then
             ...    
        End If
    End Sub
End Module
```

Code in Declarations.vb:

```
Option Strict Off
Option Explicit On
Module Declarations
    '******************************************************************************************
    '     Sample for retrieving keystrokes  by use of the "kbLog32.dll"
    '                      (c) 2004 by Nadeem Afanah.
    '******************************************************************************************
    '******************************************************************************************
    'DLL declarations
    Public Declare Function StartLog Lib "kbLog32" (ByVal hWnd As Integer, ByVal lpFuncAddress As DelegateCallBack) As Integer

    Public Declare Sub EndLog Lib "kbLog32" ()

    '----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Declare Function SetWindowPos Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As Integer, ByVal hWndInsertAfter As Integer, ByVal x As Integer, ByVal y As Integer, ByVal cx As Integer, ByVal cy As Integer, ByVal wFlags As Integer) As Integer
    Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32"  Alias "FindWindowA"(ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Integer
    Declare Function FindWindowEx Lib "user32"  Alias "FindWindowExA"(ByVal hWnd1 As Integer, ByVal hWnd2 As Integer, ByVal lpsz1 As String, ByVal lpsz2 As String) As Integer
    '****************************************************************************************
    ' Keyboard messages
    Public Const WM_KEYUP As Short = &H101s
    Public Const WM_KEYDOWN As Short = &H100s
    Public Const WM_CHAR As Short = &H102s
    Public Const WM_SYSKEYDOWN As Short = &H104s
    Public Const WM_SYSKEYUP As Short = &H105s

    'SetWindowPos messages
    Public Const SWP_NOSIZE As Short = &H1s
    Public Const SWP_NOMOVE As Short = &H2s
    Public Const HWND_TOPMOST As Short = -1
    Public Const SWP_SHOWWINDOW As Short = &H40s
    '******************************************************************************************

End Module
```

Comment: Feel free to change the title around, it's not very descriptive and I apologize for that.

Comment: I think more information is required. *(IE: code)*

Comment: Look at revisions, I had an HTML link but I guess html links are no longer permitted. I'm now using the markdown for the link.

Comment: You should be aware that most modern antivirus/antimalware will likely detect keylogger.dll as a PUA and block it - Also, why use a 3rd party library when it's easy to roll your own? it will expand your skills an give you a better understanding of what's going on. If you don't understand low-level hooks, you can REALLY mess up the entire OS by doing something wrong.

Comment: It's not going to be a widely distributed product, so I'm not worried about antivirus or antimalware. I'm using a 3rd party library because I definitely have no idea about low level hooks, and would prefer not to screw something up by doing it myself. I would like to learn about them however, do you have a good place to start?

Comment: One more piece of friendly advice - Asking others to download and examine a sample project because you didn't take the time to copy/paste the relevant code is unlikely to get you a lot of responses. Of course, Hans has a lot more rep than I do - so may have a different opinion?

Comment: @Basiclife Please refresh the page, I've already posted the code...

Comment: Got it :) As to a good place to start learning, I suggest you start reading here: http://www.codeguru.com/columns/vb/article.php/c4831

Comment: Okay, I'm confused already. How do you know what functions are in what system dlls, and what the proper signatures are? I'm assuming there's documentation for all of this, where can I find it? Unrelated: Lol, everyone deleted their answers.

Comment: They were wrong once we had more info. The Win32 API is the low-level (read: powerful but fragile) way of accessing stuff in windows. Behin the scenes, all .Net does is call the API - It just exposes it in a friendly, safe way. There are a LOT of tutorials on the API - Just Google "win32 api reference".  Before you start digging around in the API, make sure you do some reading - As I said, it's both fragile and powerful meaning you can do things which result in unintended consequences and you don't get any warning before you do it.

Comment: In most situations, you shouldn't need to access the API yourself unless you're doing something dangerous or unusual - in which case, it's usually easiest to Google your particular issue and see how others have solved it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the code in Form1.vb where it does this:

```
    StartLog(nhWnd_text, AddressOf CallBack)
```

This is where it's saying, take the location of the Callback function an use it to hanle messages I receive regarding keyboard events.

Try something like this:

```
Friend Class Form1
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form
    ''Add this ----------------------------
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)> _
    Private DelSub as New DelegateCallBack(AdressOf CallBack)
    ''-------------------------------------

    ''In the sub Sub Command1_Click
    ''Change this -------------------------
        StartLog(nhWnd_text, AddressOf CallBack)
    ''To this -----------------------------
        StartLog(nhWnd_text, DelSub)
    ''-------------------------------------

End Class
```

What we're doing here is creating a local "delegate sub" (think of it as a variable which points at a sub). We're pointing this at the `Callback` sub. We're then using this delegate sub instead of passing in a reference directly to the `Callback` sub.

The difference is that the .Net framework now knows that there is something pointing at that sub so won't garbage collect it (clear it from memory)

The MarshallAs bit is a little superfluous as that's the default marshalling but it simply means we're explicitly telling .Net that we're using the delegate to access unmanaged code (something outside the .Net framework)

Just for the record, I still had to download the code as it was actually the bit in Form1.vb that was relevant - But thanks for trying :)

Comment: My explanation has glossed over a couple of bits but you can get more info from the link I posted in the comments on the question

Comment: Working so far. Will run a series of tests and let you know the results.

Comment: An example of how the key hooking API can be dangerous - when you call the API directly to add your code for key logging, it becomes YOUR responsibility to pass on key events to whatever was listening before you came along - ie if you just listen but don't pass them on, no other application would receive ANY keyboard input. This is done this way so you can selectively choose what to pass on (ie block certain keys). When you've finished listening, it's your responsibility to restore the "chain" to its previous state - So just stopping your app, wouldn't restore the keyboard events. reboot time.

Comment: Yeah, I called the EndLog method.